# How to set mouseover/mouseout background color of a table having alternate background color

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently I have a table with several rows of data. The rows alternate between blue and white in their background-color. Whenever I mouse over I want the background-color to change temporarily to red and back to the original color of either blue or white.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var currColor = "";

    $("tr.HierarGridItem").hover(function () {
        currColor = $("tr.HierarGridItem").css("background-color");
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }, function () {
        $(this).css("background-color", currColor);

    });

});
```

The above code works fine and sets the background-color to red when I mouse over on a row. But when I mouse out, it always sets the background-color to blue instead of blue or white depending upon the original value.

Thanks

Comment: why do you use jquery for this? it can be done with pure css.. use `:hover` pseudo class..ie `td:hover{background-color:red;}` will chnge the background color only when the `<td>` is hovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set currColor to thr current item. like;

```
$("tr.HierarGridItem").hover(function () {
    currColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
}, function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", currColor);

});
```

but using css is recommended, using :hover pseudo class.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes JavaScript is a bit overkill and things can be done easier.

You probably have a CSS class for your alternating backgrounds.

```
.odd {
  background-color: white;
}

.even {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

All you need to do is add a :hover pseudo-class to your tr.

```
tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

---

```css
.odd {
  background-color: blue;
}
.even {
  background-color: white;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>foo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>bar</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>baz</td>
    <td>baz</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>qux</td>
    <td>qux</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: All my <tr> have the same class name, HierarGridItem. Added the following code tr.HierarGridItem:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
tr.HierarGridItem:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: white;
} The problem now is, only alternate rows highlight to red during hover!

Comment: Add an `!important` to the definition of the hover.